# opacity background with no opacity text

Tags: html, css, opacity

I am trying to make a div that is as wide as the screen but has a slightly dimmed out background image, but it is making any over laid text dimmed out also.  How can this be changed so only the background image is dimmed and not any overlaid text please?

```css
.venue-header-text {
  font-size: 3.5em!important;
  font-weight: 700!important;
  color: white!important;
}

.inner-slider .slide {
  padding: 100px 0 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  color: white!important;
}

.slide-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <section class="inner-slider hyr-section-height-override">
    <div class="slide" style="background-image:url('/site-data/articles/venue1/header.jpg');">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="venue-header-text">VENUE 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-overlay"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a **runnable**, non-working example code. You cannot avoid `opacity` affecting child elements, sou you must create a structure in which the element that has the `background-image` does not have child elements.

Comment: z-index maybe ?

Comment: @connexo the issue is not with opacity affecting child but a stacking issue ... the explanation is missleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the text into the `.overlay` element. Its background color will have opacity, but the text won't:

```css
.venue-header-text{
    font-size:3.5em!important;
    font-weight:700!important;
    color:white!important;
}
.inner-slider .slide {
    padding: 100px 0 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    color:white!important;
}

.slide-overlay {
    position: absolute;
     top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6)!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
<section class="inner-slider hyr-section-height-override">
<div class="slide" style="background-image:url('https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-2.jpg');">
<div class="container">

</div>
<div class="slide-overlay"><h2 class="venue-header-text">VENUE 1</h2></div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer thank you (and obvious!).  Apologies to the other people in the post - didn't mean to mislead with my question.